# XLWINGS: Cell rerference omitting columns

Tags: xlwings

Using xlwings does anyone know how to make a cell reference where some columns are dropped?

The below only command reads only A2:B2, but I want also D2:E2.

```
workSheet.range('A2:B2', 'D2:E2')
```

Comment: This is currently not supported by xlwings. You'll need to read them in as two ranges.

Comment: Man thanks @FelixZumstein! If you make your comment as answer, I'll accept it.